# Servlet on Tomcat is not accessible from my browser

Tags: windows, tomcat, mozilla

I've installed Tomcat 5.5 in windows Xp, but when I try to run my servlet by typing for instance **localhost:8081\Servlet\Servlet1** in Mozilla browser, I'm getting blank page . I already uninstalled, and then reinstalled it, but it didn't work. I've to keep refresh the page, to make my servlet run. What's the reason of not running Tomcat properly?

Comment: is that the direction of slash you're using?
is there anything running @ port 8081 (netstat -na|find "8081")?
does your servlet not have an extension?

Comment: No, there nothing at port 8081 besides Tomcat. 

Yes, I'm calling servlet by typing in that direction of slash.

Comment: How are you deploying your servlet / webapp? What's your servlet doing - "Hello, World!" or a potentially long running operation?  Have you looked in Tomcat's log to see if the servlet is throwing an exception?  I've seen some exceptions cause a blank page.

Comment: @Nate: I tried whatever you've written including checking log file, but tomcat is not displaying any output until I refresh the browser window for some time. And also log file doesn't show any effect either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward slash in your URL,

```
localhost:8081/Servlet/Servlet1
```

Comment: Tomcat still showing an output, whilst having a slash sign in opposite direction in browser address bar. I don't think this is a solution.

Comment: @JavaLearner, that's how URLs are supposed to be written. Check your address bar now - is it http://stackoverflow.com\questions\1472219\servlet-on-tomcat-is-not-accessible-from-my-browser or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472219/servlet-on-tomcat-is-not-accessible-from-my-browser ?